# Issue with CGRectMake for Button Size

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

I am having an issue with resizing my button with CGRectMake. As you can see below, it should be working, but it doesn't change at all.

```
GameTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
GameTwo.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
GameTwo.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation;
[GameTwo setTitle:(@"Game Two") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
GameTwo.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50);
[GameTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(gameTwo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:GameTwo];
```

I guess i have two questions as well. How does one change button size depending on portrait mode and then for landscape mode.

Comment: Are you aware what an 8x3 pixel button will look like?

Comment: Alright better maybe now you can see something worthwhile, now check out this article http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling and go to the section titled "Coding Layout and Size Changes"

Comment: Sweet that answers my question about Landscape vs portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GameTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
GameTwo.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
GameTwo.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation;
[GameTwo setTitle:(@"Game Two") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
GameTwo.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50); [GameTwo addTarget:self
action:@selector(gameTwo)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; [self.view
addSubview:GameTwo];
```

Works perfect. (This is what was in the original question)
The issue was I was trying to use another function to place were the button should go. I didn't understand that the first two variables in this case `(10, 10...)` were the placement of the button. Now i do.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb for "**It should be working, but it doesn't change at all**" bugs is to search for the bug elsewhere.

Did you check the `GameTwo` class implementation (and superclasses) thoroughly?
Did you set an autoresizing mask?
Do you somewhere set the frame on a bounds change notification?

Comment: This is a good rule. I figured it out actually. Let me post the answer. Sorry about that.